# Ranger Has incorrect colorsheme when opened with firefox

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, ranger, alacritty

I couldn't really find a better place to ask this question and figured that if anyone would know it would be you guys.

So when I open ranger it inherits my colorscheme and styling from alacritty, however whenever ranger is invoked by firefox (set as default in my mimetypes config) It completely flashbangs me with what looks like the default tty font and a very, very white background.

I was wondering how to make this not happen.

Here are screenshots with the comparison: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksvbw.jpg

Edit: I have discovered that it gives this error in terminal that is running firefox `term: cannot load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"`

this clued me in that my firefox is run in some type of compatibility layer, probably because of my window manager OS combo.

I suppose extra context that I am running Arch Linux with sway/wayland as my window manager. A work around for now is using nautilus instead, but I would still prefer ranger if at all possible.

Comment: And you're sure you're starting alacritty and not xterm or other terminal emulator?

Comment: Yes, it's in my sway config @MarcusMüller. I did some more prodding and found out there's a whole rabbithole with this type of issue having to do with portals and protocols

Comment: That's exactly why I'm asking :) OK, so what specifically did you put into your mimetypes config to launch ranger in alacritty? Maybe we can coerce alacritty to do what you want, but for now I simply don't know where to start reproducing your problem

Comment: I did `inode/directory=ranger.desktop` in the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Comment: ah! But I don't know your `ranger.desktop`